# Получение имени сервера по IP

Tags: c#, .net, dns

С толкнулся с такой проблемой, что метод не может получить имя сервера по IP.
Для некоторых серверов это работает, а для некоторых нет. Выдает ошибку HostNotFound.

```
    internal async static Task<IPHostEntry> GetMachineNameFromIPAddressAsync(
        String address, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var host = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(IPAddress.Parse(address));
        var list = host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault();
        var name = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(list);
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Вероятно, DNS сервер тупо не знает имени для указанного адреса... попробуйте зафиксировать, у какого DNS для какого адреса не возвращается имя, и проверить, даёт ли этот сервер имя для этого адреса иными средствами (тем же nslookup)...

Comment: через nslookup результат тот же

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут ничего не поделаешь.

Если у сервера прописана PTR запись в обратной зоне, то резолвиться будет, если нет - то нет. То есть это зависит от владельца домена, а не от вашего кода.

Чаще прописывают PTR в тех случаях, когда с этого IP должна уходить почта - это одно из важных условий непопадания писем в спам у нормальных почтовых провайдеров. Поэтому те, кто занимается настройкой почты покупают нормальный хостинг, где можно поднять DKIM, настроить SPF и настроить обратную зону.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И очень часто обратную зону не прописать на дешёвых хостингах - тупо в админке нет такой возможности.

Comment: понял. спасибо)